# Rails 4 static subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, subdomain

I can't set root path for subdomain.

This is my `routes.rb` part:

```
constraints subdomain: 'blog' do
  scope :module => "blog", :as => "blog" do
    resources :posts
  end
end

root 'statics#index'
```

When I am visiting `blog.example.com` I've got `static#index` action response and get `posts#index`, when visiting `blog.example.com/posts`.

I want to set root path for blog.example.com pointing to posts#index.

No effect for this:

```
match '/' => 'posts#index', :constraints => { :subdomain => 'blog' }, via: [:get]
```

Comment: Did you care about the order in your routes.rb file? Rails will take the first matching route. So always place more general routes **after** constrained routes

Comment: Yes, as in example, 'main' root is a last record in **routes.rb**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10180#issuecomment-16270920) works for me with separate namespaces for each subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should still be able to call `root` within the `constraints` block:

```
constraints subdomain: 'blog' do
  root :to => 'posts#index' # Perhaps this needs to be `blog/posts#index`?

  scope :module => "blog", :as => "blog" do
    resources :posts
  end
end

root 'statics#index'
```

Comment: It isn't work at all: when I'm run rails server I've got an error:
`Uncaught exception: Invalid route name, already in use: 'root' 
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the ":as" option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with "resources" as explained here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created`
When I use `root :to => 'posts#index', :as => "blog"` I can start rails-server, but blog.example.com pointing to statics#index